# target css of images inside a body class

Tags: html, css, joomla

In Joomla I have several pages that I have applied the CSS class of "government" to the body tag of.  I need to style the thumbnail img tags inside the btcontensliderxxx divs on those pages to have a red 3px border.  I will be doing the same with other categories with their own colors.  [This link goes to my first test page](http://www.teachertravelguide.com/~sawstemp/newtv/beyond-the-badge) if you want to see the code.

You will see that right now those thumbnail images have a blue border around them but I need it to be red since it is in that government category.

You will see the government class in the body tag but I can't figure out how to easily target those btcontentsliderxxx divs.  Everything I have tried so far has failed.  I need something generic that will work regardless of what the xxx is at the end of the btcontentsliderxxx class.

Let me just admit that I stink at CSS but would be very grateful for any assistance with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
body.government .bt-cs .bt-inner img {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Applying a rule for when body has the class `government`.

[image: css inspector - override]

You can see how it overrides the default styles through the devtools inspector.